# Chinese character displaying wrongly/differently on Windows

Tags: windows, cjk, chinese-locale

I notice the word 门 is displaying differently when it is being typed on certain applications such as the search bar in Chrome。

Some website are also showing the wrong character.

[[image: Wrong Chinese character]

This only happens in Windows. How do I fix this and show the correct Chinese character?

Answer (score 0):

The character displayed is correct. It's just a stylistic variation – seems to happen mostly in Japanese fonts rather than Chinese. Make sure to choose a Simplified Chinese font, and it should display as expected.

[image: Font Variations]